# Setting up JBoss v5.0 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jms

I'm trying to do a few JMS tutorials. Many of them seem to use the server I've mentioned in the title. It's found in the JBoss folder in the "Define a New Server" window. For example, the tutorial here:
http://aalaapa.com/img/eclipsejbossserver5.JPG

Problem is, in the "Define a New Server" window, the only folders I have to choose from are Apache, Basic, JBoss Community and JBoss Enterprise Middleware. Is there some addition plugin I need?

Oh, I'm using Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you click on "Download additional server adapters", you should have a dialog where you can install an appropriate server connector (in your case it would be the "JbossAS Tools").
However i would strongly recommend to use JBoss 7, since that version is a full certified EE6 compliant application server

Edit: If you have the menu point "JBoss Community" then is is very likely that the JBoss Tools are already installed. So just take one of that connectors (3.2 to 7.1 should be included) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, and just noticed I linked the image not the tutorial so sorry about that.